# ASP.NET CORE async operation user alert

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, asynchronous

I am making an asp.net core app ( offiline app : client and server will be same machine ). in which I take some user input and post it to controller
Then I run a very time taking algorithm on server side and I have to give some visual output later on another page after my work on backend is finished.

I want to know a simple asyncronous way in which, when user presses submit button , my controller performs all backend algo in async way and I can keep on notifying the user how much work is done, 
**forexample** after every step of background algo, I want to visually notify or show the user progress, may be with written headings or maybe a progress bar of bootstrap.

How can I achieve this?
Thanks In advance.

Comment: You could use [SignalR](https://github.com/aspnet/signalr)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you check [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr). You should be able to use it for communication from the server back to the client using web sockets.